# Jest log message on assertion failure using test.each

Tags: jestjs

I am trying to log a URL on test failure. I am using `test.each(testData)` where `testData` will pass an object with a `url` property for each test run.

On assertion failure, I'd like to log out the `url` that failed the test but I am finding it surprisingly difficult to do.

Is this even possible? Passing an argument to an assertion like this: `expect(metaTag).not.toBeFalsy('url goes here');` won't work. Nor will throwing an Error. Nor will changing the title of each generated test (with `test.each`) as at the time of title definition, I don't have access to the `url`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-expect-message

`npm i -D jest-expect-message`

Add this to package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "jest-expect-message"
  },
```

Use:

```
  expect(
    metaTag,
    `Could not find metaTag with selector ${robotsMetaTagSelector} for url ${url}`
  ).not.toBeFalsy();
```

If anyone knows of a better or in-built solution - that would be a better answer.